# batch file: working with list elements in nested loop

Tags: list, batch-file, nested-loops

I've been trying to get following batch script working, looks like I need to ask someone with more expertise in Batch, as I don't have any clue, why it keeps not working. My intention is to get two elements of the list `VAR` gets swapped:

```
    @echo off

    rem enable delayed expansion, required for extended usage of environment variables
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

    set VAR=abcd efgh ijkl mnopq rstvw qwert yxcva rtzewrw yxvys
    set fst=qwert
    set scnd=rstvw

    call :test %VAR%

    :test
    SETLOCAL

    for %%i in (%*) do (
        for %%j in (%* %%i) do (
            if %scnd% equ %%i (
                if %fst% equ %%j (
                echo "gotcha before swapping: " "i: " %%i "j: " %%j
                    set tempor=%%i
                    set i=%%j
                    set j=!tempor!
                    echo "gotcha after swapping: " "i: " !i! "j: " !j!          
                    set List=!List! %%j %%i
                )
            )
        )
        set List=!List! %%i
        echo "List: " !List!
    )

    ENDLOCAL
    goto :eof

    :ende
```

I am trying to get the List to look like this:

```
abcd efgh ijkl mnopq qwert rstvw yxcva rtzewrw yxvys
```

where the fst (for first element) and scnd (second element) get swapped.

The output is like this: `"List: "  abcd efgh ijkl mnopq qwert rstvw rstvw qwert yxcva rtzewrw yxvys`, so I get double entry of `qwert` and `rstvw`, and I know it is because of the position of `set List=!List! %%i`.

At least I know, the *swapping* is working.
But my problem is: if I put this in the `else` branch, as I would normally do in any other script language, the List will be filled with `%%i` and `%%j` in every loop, so it becomes useless....

Comment: If you put the big for loop inside an if-else branch/clause (whatever that's called), it should still work.

Comment: You mean by `if %scnd% neq %%i` and `if %fst% neq %%j` ?, the `%%i` and `%%j` haven't been initialized in this point, so I don't quite get what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem appears to be that `%%i` and `%i%` are entirely *different* variables. You cannot assign values to `%%i` - only the `for` command can.

You appear to be attempting to perform an insertion-sort to build a sorted list of strings. Your code-structure may be a legacy of edits to present the problem, but as posted, the routine will be re-entered by flow-through. Also, since the routine `:test` is enclosed in a setlocal/endlocal bracket,  changes to `list` will not be visible outside of the `:test` routine. And having two `setlocal` commands in succession establishes two *nested* local environments. *Both* of the options can be specified simultaneously in one `setlocal` statement. Note that `setlocal` is not a switch - it establishes a local environment (and yes, microsoft has been asked to establish `delayed expansion` and the like as separate swtich-type operations like `echo on/off`)

Also note that your generated list contains a leading space. I've followed that idea with the following substitute routine:

REM

```
SET "list2="
for %%i in (%*) do (
 REM %%i has each element in turn
 SET "startlist= "
 SET "endlist= "
 IF defined list2 for %%j in (!list2!) do (
  IF "%%j" lss "%%i" (
   SET "startlist=!startlist!%%j "
  ) ELSE (
   SET "endlist=!endlist!%%j "
  )
 )
 SET "list2=!startlist!%%i!endlist:~0,-1!"
)
ECHO "List2:" %list2%+
```

(I've added a `+` to the end to show the end of the string `list2`.

---

Yes - specifying the required output in the original question makes the problem easy to solve

```dos
:test
SETLOCAL
SET "List="
for %%i in (%*) do (
 if %fst% equ %%i ( SET "List=!List! %scnd%"
 ) ELSE (
  if %scnd% equ %%i ( SET "List=!List! %fst%"
  ) ELSE set List=!List! %%i
 )
 echo "List: " !List!
)
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```

I'm assuming for lack of information otherwise that it's guaranteed that `fst` and `scnd` are both guaranteed to appear exactly once in the input.

Comment: hi magoo, thanks for the clue. It looks like I haven't explained correctly what I need: The original script should definitly swap two given element within the list. I've figured out myself how to sort a list (e.g. using `sort`, or like your example using `lss` or `leq` etc.).  Still my problem is that I couldn't figured out how to skip collecting `%%i` and `%%j` again when I've swapped them, thus double entry in `List`. Let's see how to solve this...

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us what your desired resultant list should be, given your starting list.

Comment: Sure, sorry, I should have done it directly in the question. I am trying to get the List looks like this: `abcd efgh ijkl mnopq qwert rstvw yxcva rtzewrw yxvys` where the `fst` (for first element) and `scnd` (second element) gets swapped. Like in the original question I've mentioned, they are already get swapped, but after that they get pushed in the List again, thus the double entry...

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. Now I'm really wondering why I've tried to solve it in lot complicated way. Have a nice new year eve